# Android: Workmanager Dagger (Did you try to initialize it manually without disabling WorkManagerInitializer)

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

Few days ago I've been working on implementing Dagger combined/inject with Android Workmanager. Basically this works perfectly, however I get an error when I open the application (application is active in the background).

> WorkManager is already initialized.  Did you try to initialize it manually without disabling WorkManagerInitializer? See WorkManager#initialize(Context, Configuration) or the class level Javadoc for more information.

Have you experienced this problem before, and how do I fix it? Below are some snapshots from my application code.

**Manifest file**:

```
<provider
            android:name="androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerInitializer"
            android:authorities="{packagename}.workmanager-init"
            android:exported="false"
            android:enabled="false"
            tools:node="remove" />
```

**WorkerBindingModule**:

```
@Module
public interface WorkerBindingModule {

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @WorkerKey(VVSArtikelWorker.class)
    GithubWorkerFactory bindVVSArtikelWorker(VVSArtikelWorker.Factory factory);

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @WorkerKey(ArticleInventoryWorker.class)
    GithubWorkerFactory bindArticleInventoryWorker(ArticleInventoryWorker.Factory factory);
}
```

**WorkerKey**:

```
@MapKey
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface WorkerKey {

    Class<? extends ListenableWorker> value();
}
```

**AppComponent** :

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {
        AndroidSupportInjectionModule.class,
        ActivityBuildersModule.class,
        ViewModelFactoryModule.class,
        RoomModule.class,
        NetworkModule.class,
        WorkerBindingModule.class
})
public interface AppComponent extends AndroidInjector<XVSApplication> {

    UserSessionManager userSessionManager();
    XVSWorkerFactory appGithubWorkerFactory();

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        Builder application(Application application);

        AppComponent build();

    }
}
```

**XVSApplication** :

```
public class XVSApplication extends DaggerApplication {

    @Override
    protected AndroidInjector<? extends DaggerApplication> applicationInjector() {
        return DaggerAppComponent.builder().application(this).build();
    }
}
```

**BaseActivity** :

```
public class BaseActivity extends DaggerAppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "BaseActivity";

    @Inject
    public UserSessionManager userSessionManager;

    @Inject
    XVSWorkerFactory factory;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        subscribeObservers();
        configurationBuilderWorkManager();
        setupPeriodicWork();
    }
.....
    private void setupPeriodicWork() {
//        Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder().setRequiresBatteryNotLow(true).setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED).build();
        PeriodicWorkRequest periodicWorkRequestVVSArticle = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(VVSArtikelWorker.class, 12, TimeUnit.HOURS).build();
        WorkManager.getInstance(this).enqueue(periodicWorkRequestVVSArticle);

        PeriodicWorkRequest periodicWorkRequestArticleOrder = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(ArticleInventoryWorker.class, 1, TimeUnit.HOURS)
                .build();
        WorkManager.getInstance(this).enqueue(periodicWorkRequestArticleOrder);
    }

  private void configurationBuilderWorkManager() {
        Configuration config = new Configuration.Builder()
                .setWorkerFactory(factory)
                .build();

        WorkManager.initialize(this, config);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation for [`WorkManager.initialize()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager#initialize(android.content.Context,%20androidx.work.Configuration)):

> This method throws an exception if it is called multiple times.

While each instance of `BaseActivity` only calls `onCreate()` once, you cannot expect there to be only one instance of `BaseActivity` during your `Application`'s lifetime.  Specifically, this is unavoidable if the user launches your app, exits by pressing the back button, then launches your app again later.  The second instance will also try to initialize `WorkManager` in `onCreate()`, which throws an exception.

The same documentation suggests a better place to initialize `WorkManager`:

> - Invoke this method in `Application#onCreate` or a `ContentProvider`. Note that this method **must** be invoked in one of these two places or you risk getting a `NullPointerException` in `getInstance(Context)`.